# How to get the last accessed partitions from AWS Glue using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

Im using the below function to get all partitions from AWS Glue catalog table. There are some tables in the database that has more than 50K partitions. Is it possible to get only the partitions based on the 'LastAccessTime' attribute. I know I can filter from the list of all partitions but I want to see if there is any possible way, using the 'Expression' property of the get_partitions or something so I can avoid scanning the entire catalog table

```
def get_glue_partitions(glue_client, database_name, table_name):
    """Grabs all partitions for a table, and iterates through pagination."""
    partitions = []

    next_token = ''
    while True:  
        resp = glue_client.get_partitions(
            DatabaseName=database_name,
            TableName=table_name,
            NextToken=next_token)
        partitions += resp['Partitions']

        if 'NextToken' not in resp:
            break
        next_token = resp['NextToken']
    return partitions
```

Comment: how is the data partitioned? I believe we can use --expression only on the columns on which data is partitioned!

Comment: yes that is correct. I tried using --expression to filter by 'LastAccessTime' and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

As I've come to discover, the way the `--expression` filter works is by filtering on the partition column(s) *defined in your table* rather than properties defined in the AWS API. For instance, if your table is partitioned on `create_date`, the expression in the API call can reference this column:

```py
glue_client.get_partitions(
    DatabaseName=database_name,
    TableName=table_name,
    NextToken=next_token,
    Expression="create_date > '2023-01-01'",
)
```

To my knowledge, I don't believe this expression filter is able to operate on other properties defined on a Glue Partition object unfortunately.